# Why is my code failing to find length of longest arithmetic subsequence?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

The question is to find the length of subsequence in an array that is arithmetic in nature. The question can be found on leetcode.

My code is:

```
    def longestArithSeqLength(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        if len(nums)==1:
            return 1
        dp = []
        for i in nums:
            dp.append(dict())
        max_so_far = 1
        for i in range(1,len(nums)):
            for j in range(i-1,-1,-1):
                difference = nums[i] - nums[j]
                if difference in dp[j]:
                    dp[i][difference] = dp[j][difference]+1
                    max_so_far = max(max_so_far,dp[i][difference]+1)        
                else:
                    dp[i][difference] = 1
                    max_so_far = max(max_so_far,dp[i][difference]+1)
        return max_so_far
```

In this, at each index, I have a dictionary calculating the length of subsequence-1 till that index for each difference with previous elements. But for a test case, my code is failing:

```
[22,8,57,41,36,46,42,28,42,14,9,43,27,51,0,0,38,50,31,60,29,31,20,23,37,53,27,1,47,42,28,31,10,35,39,12,15,6,35,31,45,21,30,19,5,5,4,18,38,51,10,7,20,38,28,53,15,55,60,56,43,48,34,53,54,55,14,9,56,52]
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. Can someone explain where my logic is wrong and why it's not able to handle this test case?

Comment: What do you mean by "arithmetic in nature"?

Comment: What is the expected result for that test case, and how is it determined?

Comment: The expected answer is 6. I am getting 5. By arithmetic in nature I mean the subsequence should generate an arithmetic progression

Comment: Or simply the subsequence should be in AP(Arithmetic Progression)

Answer (score 0):

I now know my mistake. In the jth loop, I am starting from right to left, so if the difference is seen again, the length of left one will be updated rather than the right one. This may sound confusing but let me explain.

For sequence -2,-1,0,10,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2

When I am at element 1(ith loop element) and i iterate from 0 to -2(right to left in jth loop), the first time it sees 0, it updates difference 1 as difference of 1 in 0th(second zero) dictionary+1. Then it goes to left side 0 and again sees difference 1 and updates difference 1 as dictionary value 1 of 0th element(first one) which has lower length of subsequence than second occurence. So if I simply run the loop left to right instead of right to left, this solves the problem.

Code now looks like:

```
def longestArithSeqLength(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        if len(nums)==1:
            return 1
        dp = []
        for i in nums:
            dp.append(dict())
        max_so_far = 1
        for i in range(1,len(nums)):
            ####   RUNNNING LOOP LEFT TO RIGHT NOW   ####
            for j in range(i):
                difference = nums[i] - nums[j]
                if difference in dp[j]:
                    dp[i][difference] = dp[j][difference]+1
                    max_so_far = max(max_so_far,dp[i][difference]+1)        
                else:
                    dp[i][difference] = 1
                    max_so_far = max(max_so_far,dp[i][difference]+1)
        return max_so_far
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def longestArithSeqLength(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    if len(nums) <= 1:
        return len(nums)
    dp = []
    for i in nums:
        dp.append(dict())
    max_so_far = 0  # Initialize max_so_far to 0 instead of 1
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            difference = nums[i] - nums[j]
            if difference in dp[j]:
                dp[i][difference] = dp[j][difference] + 1
                max_so_far = max(max_so_far, dp[i][difference])  # Update max_so_far without adding 1
            else:
                dp[i][difference] = 1
                max_so_far = max(max_so_far, dp[i][difference])
    return max_so_far + 1  # Add 1 to max_so_far to account for the current element
```

Comment: You want to add more context to your answer. Explain what you did and how you fixed the problem.

Comment: Still failing for the test case I mentioned

Comment: format your code..